# Please give me a sanity check React JSX inline style

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, inline-styles

React jsx:

```
return (
  <div
    key={`freq-${i + 3}`}
    className='freq'
    style={{ transform: 'scaleX(0.2)' }}
  />
);
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="freq" style=""></div>
```

If I change the style property to anything else it works:

```
return (
  <div
    key={`freq-${i + 3}`}
    className='freq'
    style={{ transform: 'rotate(360deg)' }}
  />
);
```

Rendered:

```
<div class="freq" style="transform: rotate(360deg);"></div>
```

Comment: It seems to work for me

Comment: Same here. Works well